# What are the benefits of using RDBMS over ElasticSearch?

Tags: rdbms, elasticsearch

Is there any reason why one would want to design a system using an RDBMS other than legacy factors, team's experience, cost etc.? 
Fundamentally, is there something that an RDBMS can do better than a document store system like ES?
I'm just starting with ElasticSearch and so far it looks unnecessary to have RDBMS as the primary data store for an application. Also, my experience is with applications that essentially store `objects` into a database thus requiring ORMs because the application is written in an object oriented language, is there a case where this would not be so?

Answer (score 1):

Systems in which data integrity is extremely important, have transactions and are not expected to have huge scaling requirements are best modeled as RDBMS's. For example, financial reporting systems used for company finances, payments, billing, taxes. It is simple to model the relationships in an RDBMS and query with SQL, rather then write the code to join and filter for the data that you need from different documents.

Answer (score 1):

This is, I guess, a strongly opinion based question although there are some hard facts:

### RDBMS

- Most RDBMS stick to ACID which brings transactions, isolation between transactions and many more (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID; many more excellent posts are out there)
- Mostly standardized API such as ODBC, JDBC with higher level abstractions such as JPA for the Java world
- Drivers for the different operating systems, mostly vendor provided
- Depending on the database system, there are tons of tuning options (table spaces, buffer pools, ...)
- Tons of existing integrations of 3rd party tools
- RDBMS are still a known area and most managers/devs/architects/ops know, how to deal with them
- RDBMS sometimes provide  vendor-specific features (MySQL's InMemory tables, PostgreSQL Key-Value-API, and many others)
- You're required (or you should) use connection pooling if you run applications with multiple threads
- HA is very expensive when using RDBMS (Oracle's RAC, MySQL via DRBD)
- "Oracle DBA" is nearly a standardized Job description
- RDBMS solve some problems for you which you would be required to do additional effort in ES (e. g. handling writes in a transactional way)

### ElasticSearch

- ES provides atomicity per document. Documents are guaranteed to be consistent and written to disk. Since there are no multi-document translations, isolation is not applicable here (at least not the way, you know it from RDBMS)
- ES has its very own API and provides clients for all major programming languages that work on various operating systems. You always have  the HTTP API option, no matter which OS you use.
- Higher level API's are available for ES such as Spring Data ElasticSearch
- There is a continuously increasing number of integrations
- You are not required to use connection pooling since HTTP connections are closed (but you could if you use Connection: Keep-Alive)
- ES provides a lot of interesting built-in features whereas RDBMS need extra plugins/feature packs (e. g. MySQL's Extensions for Spatial Data)
- ES fits nicely in the Cloud/Micro service thinking: Just add a node and it's on. You're HA in a few console commands.
- There are less certified ops of ES (in comparison to RDBMS ops)
- ES is a relatively new product, so managers/devs/architects/ops in doubt might argue against it (*opinion based*)

Hope, the post got not too opinion based and HTH.